# Does remove document automatically remove the index that reference this document?

Tags: index, mongodb

I am wondering if removing the document will automatically update the index if this document is referenced?

Answer (score 1):

Delete just put a flag on the document that is deleted. I am not sure but i think it doesn't reorganize the indexes at the same time, if that is your question, because reorganize the b-tree is an expensive operation.

Comment: If a document is removed, it is removed from the index. If it wasn't, a "concurrent" query could return a stale reference. However, this _should_ be a rather fast operation, as indices _should_ be kept in RAM. If they aren't, a slow removal isn't your only concern.

Comment: I was referring to physical level , the question is not very clear maybe @Kristen can rephrase it

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg that could be expanded into an answer ;)